# Find the set of cyclotomic cosets of q modulo n

Tags: finite-fields, factoring, cyclotomic-polynomials

Calculating finite field and factoring $x^n - 1$ over $GF(q)$ first step is to calculate cyclotomic cosets.

For example :

For $n=9,q=2$

$C_1=\{1,2,4,8,7,5\} = C_4 = C_8 = C_7 = C_5$

$C_3=\{3,6\} = C_6$

$C_0=\{0\}$

And the set of cyclotomic cosets of 2 mod 9 is then $C= \{C_0,C_1,C_3\}$

How to calculate those values?

Comment: Use the definition of a cyclotomic coset? The ($q$)-cyclotomic coset of $i$ modulo $n$ consists of the elements
$$C(i,n)=\{iq^j\mid j\ge0\}\subset \Bbb{Z}_n.$$
Here
$$C(1,9)=\{1,2,4,8,16=7,32=5(,64=1)\}$$